# Give the equation for this plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Well, the line $r$ is defined by:

$$x = 2y-3$$
$$z = -y+1$$
So if I set $y=1$ i get this vector:
$$(-1,1,0)$$

I need to find the equation of the plane `perpendicular` to this **line** and that contains the point **A = (1,2,3)**

Well, I've just found a normal vector by setting $y = 1$ and I've got the normal vector $(-1,1,0)$.

I know that the vector $(x,y,z)-(1,2,3)$ must be on the plane, so it's `dot product` with the normal vector must be equals 0. So:

$$(x-1, y-2, z-3) \cdot (-1,1,0) = 0$$

Then the plane equation should be the dot product solved, but it's not working. Can somebody say what I've done worng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is uniquely determined by two points but you choose only one point, which causes your normal vector wrong.

Comment: But the $x$ and $z$ coordinates depend only on $y$, if I set $y=something$ then I should find the normal vector, I guess...

Comment: @user108425 Except (0,0,0) is on the line, too.

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: @shuchang-zang how can I find the normal vector?

Comment: @user108425 Choose points $p_1,p_2$ on the line and set normal vector as $n=p_1-p_2$